# Relative magnitude of the crystal field and spin-orbit coupling

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, crystal-field-theory, epr-spectroscopy

In the EPR part of the book 'Physical methods in Inorganic Chemistry' by S. Drago i found that relative magnitudes of crystal field and spin-orbit coupling affect the g values.
I understand that the chemical environment of a metal complex partly removes the orbital degeneracy, but i don't find the way to imagine a sustaining effect which implies that if an electron has an orbital angular momentum this is manteined by coupling to the spin angular momentum. I have read that consequently a net orbital magnetic moment results, giving a g value different from the free electron.
I also can't imagine how when the crystal field increases the LS coupling is broken down completely.